# What is the cross-platform way to add a JavaScript module to the global scope?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, global-scope, self-invoking-function

I was having a look at the source code of [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/blob/master/store.js), in particular how it adds itself to the global scope:

```
if (typeof module != 'undefined') { module.exports = store }
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { define(store) }
else { this.store = store }
```

I understand the last statement `this.store = store`, but how about the other ones? What are the `module` and `define` functions? Won't `this.store = store` already work on all the browsers?

More generally, what is the correct, cross-browser way, to add a module to the global scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first case is for [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/), which is most notably used in Node.js and is a flavor of AMD ([Asynchronous Module Definition](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)). A module is a JavaScript file that gets executed with a global module object defined. Whatever that file sets to `module.exports` will be available to other parts of the app, and everything else in the file will remain private to just that module. Here is a [good blog post](http://dailyjs.com/2010/10/18/modules/) on it.

The second one is for another flavor of AMD, which is most commonly implemented with [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). It's a very similar idea to CommonJs, but is more commonly found in the browser. The Dojo framework is one good example of an amd based framework. The Jquery community is getting behind amd a lot as well. `define` tells the amd system that you are giving it a module that the rest of the app can pull in by using `require`.

The final version is the common scenario of running in a plain jane browser. `this` is most likely DOMWindow, and thus the store object becomes global across the whole webpage.